# Display partial view as POPUP in mvc2?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, popup, partial-views

I want to show result ( as list ) with fade effect in mvc2 .

Current it shows on same page and main form is displaying below result. How to display partial view results with fade effect popup in mvc2.

Suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Create a action method in your controller which returns a partialview

from you main page. write a js/jquery code to open a popup. you can use the fade effect from  http://jqueryui.com/effect/

call you action method to load your partial view